# Unable to detect droppable event on body using jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating to create drag and drop functionality using `jquery UI`. However , the drop event isn't getting triggered when I drop something on the `body`

Here is my demo code.Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ysptW/1/

Comment: Maybe this will help http://forum.jquery.com/topic/body-droppable

Comment: @ExplosionPills : It isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 $( "body" ).droppable({
```

to:

```
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ysptW/1/) is the jsFiddle

**UPDATE**

You almost had it, the problem was that your body didn't have a height, which was identified by giving it a css border.  Once a height was set using `body{height:200px;}` then it worked.

new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/ysptW/2/) in response to comments:

Comment: Guys,I know it works for `#droppable` . I need it to work for body.

Comment: Can I ask why you need that requirement?

Comment: It's a bit complicated to explain here because it involves a lot of stuff.To explain it in brief,I have a organisational chart built using `jquery`.If I `drag` a `node`,the `node` gets duplicated and when I drop it on the `body`,I need to do some computations and if I drop it on the chart itself,the duplicate `node` should get deleted.I have completed the other sections.I just need to figure out how to `fire an event` when I drop it on the `body`.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, I think we were misled by the 'droppable' section.  So in fact you're not actually interested in the 'droppable' div, you want the droppable event fired anywhere in the html <body> section?, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/ysptW/2/)

Comment: Exactly.Sorry that my post was misleading.

Comment: Just a question though.Can't I set `style = "height:100%;width:100%";` for the body to do the same.

Comment: I'm no css expert, but I think 100% will only work when relative to a parent element, which doesn't exist for <body>.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code from

```
$("body").droppable
```

to

```
$("#droppable").droppable...
```

You can check the same at 
    http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/yEvsY/

For more info, visit http://jqueryui.com/droppable

Comment: what's the point of replying with EXACTLY the same solution as mine?

Comment: when I opened the page it wasn't having anything...and after posting I saw that even you have answered it...

Comment: Guys,I know it works for `#droppable` . I need it to work for body.